# What is this type of statement called?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Having made (in vain) a good faith effort to answer this question without troubling the esteemed community, I pray the following expert-level advice on what I think all will agree is a thought-provoking matter:

What type of statement do you refer to if you call something by what it is not, like:

"That is not good"  instead of  "That is bad"

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *[negative strenghtening](http://bfy.tw/6v9D)* by Larry Horn in his classic 1989 book **A natural history of negation.** Horn notes that the phenomenon is conventionally classified as a case of **litotes** (emphasis through understatement).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it belongs to speech called circumlocution (talking around something); if the idea is to lessen the impact of the negative - say, telling someone their idea is bad - you could classify it as a [euphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) or understatement.

Also relevant, if conditions are involved, is the idea of [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition). A contrapositive is an equally-true restatement of a condition in negative terms. E.g., "if something is a bat, it is a mammal" has the contrapositive "if something is not a mammal, then it must not be a bat."

Comment: Thank you for the reply. All of these seem relevant, however I was just wondering if there was not maybe something more specific?